# Nhibernate fetch

Tags: nhibernate

I fetch all data from table by hql query  like"from table"(this query return only one column)
Size of table 79000000(79 M) rows
I limit size of answer by SetFirstResult(0)  SetFetchSize(2000). 
It doesn't help .
NHibernate throw OutOfMemory Exception.

I use Oracle. 
Thx

Answer (score 0):

If you want to limit the resultset to 2000 you should use SetMaxResults(2000).